# Fetching keys using value in KeyValuePair in List

Tags: c#

I stuck up with the logic. 
I've the list

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

The output of items would be

```
0,AOP
1,AOP
2,AOP
3,Solid
4,Solid
```

I need to get the keys for same value(AOP=0,1,2). How could this be achieved?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I just stuck with the code. I could write till add items to the list. I couldn't write the segregation part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This

This will give you dictionary with your values as keys and Values are List of keys having same values.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> result = items.GroupBy(d => d.Value).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Select(r => r.Key).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by value:

```
var groups = times.GroupBy(item => item.Value).ToList();

foreach(var g in groups)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Value = " + g.Key);

  foreach(var member in g)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("\tKey = " + member.Key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two outcomes, so I'll provide you with both.

```
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "AOP"),
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "AOP"),
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "AOP"),
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "Solid"),
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "Solid"),
        };

        // assuming we want to group key
        foreach (var value in items.GroupBy(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.Key);
        }

        // now lets invert the keys and values
        foreach (var value in items.GroupBy(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value))
        {
            IList<int> allValues = value.Select(item => item.Key).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", value.Key, allValues.Select(v => v.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b));            }
        }
```

Comment: How can I push those same values of different keys to different list?   I mean 0,1,2 of AOP alone to list and 3,4 of Solid to list?

Comment: I've updated the example.  Basically, the return value from the GroupBy (the IGrouping) comes in two parts.  The first is the Key which you can see is value.Key.  The second is not so obvious at first glance - the IGrouping itself is an IEnumerable of the elements that were grouped.  All you need to do is select out the key and then call ToList to generate the list of keys.